# Setting maximum slope/flow length in flow accumulation using SAGA?

Tags: saga, slope, catchment-area, flow-accumulation

I like to limit the slope length in SAGA GIS. In other words, the flow accumulation should only account for a specific length until a subsurface flow initiates  and surface flow stops. Actually, I have flow length up to 2000 m.

In SAGA GIS, I only find tools to calculate the flow length but no tool to set a maximum slope/flow length threshold.

Do you have any idea for a workaround?